# What do I misunderstand about instance methods?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, libsodium

So I have a schema with this method:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = (candidatePassword) => {
    let candidateBuf = Buffer.from(candidatePassword, 'ascii');
    if (sodium.crypto_pwhash_str_verify(this.password, candidateBuf)) {
        return true;
    };
    return false;
};
```

it's called thusly:

```
User.find({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
    isValid = user[0].comparePassword(req.body.password);
    // more stuff
}
```

This results in `Error: argument hash must be a buffer`

I am able to verify that user[0] is a valid user, obviously because it sucessfully calls the `comparePassword` method, and it's the libsodium function that fails.

Further test has shown that `this.password` is undefined. In fact, `this` is undefined in the `comparePassword` method. My understanding was that `this` would refer to the object from which the method is called, in this case, `user[0]`.

So what's the correct way to refer to the object calling it's own instance method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` doesn't always work the way you think it will inside an arrow function.

fat arrow functions perform lexical scoping (essentially looking at the surrounding code and defining `this` based on context.)

If you change back to regular callback function notation you will probably get the results you want:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword) {
  let candidateBuf = Buffer.from(candidatePassword, 'ascii');
  if (sodium.crypto_pwhash_str_verify(this.password, candidateBuf)) {
    return true;
  };
  return false;
};
```

For examples of binding  `this`:
https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/